# Use renv for private GitLab package

Tags: r, gitlab, devtools, install.packages, renv

I have a local GitLab account with an R package that can be installed by:

```
devtools::install_git( 
  url = "http://my-gitlab/my-projects/package",
  credentials = git2r::cred_user_pass("user", "pass")
)
```

When I run `renv::init()` the package source is unknown. The [getting started article](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) does give details about how to setup functions to deal with private repos but I can't figure it out for GitLab when using `devtools` and `git2r::cred_user_pass`. I could store `GIT_USER` and `GIT_PASSWORD` in an `.Renviron` file but I'm not sure how to force the `init` function to user `devtools::install_git` with those credentials. I did try but then I get an error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://my-gitlab': No such device or address
```

All the example options they provide use a GitLab token for authentication:

```
# use a named list directly
options(renv.auth = list(
  MyPackage = list(GITHUB_PAT = "<pat>")
))
```

Perhaps there is a better way to install from a local GitLab repo that will work better with `renv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else having the same problem, this worked for me (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/476)):

- Create a PAT in GITLAB making sure to set the SCOPE to `api`. Note: I'm not sure this has to be 'api' I didn't check all options but it worked for me
- Set the PAT as a env variable using `Sys.setenv(GITLAB_PAT = <...>)`
- Set the gitlab host server as an option using `options(renv.config.gitlab.host = "http://my-gitlab-server")`. Note: I had to include "http://" to get it working.
- Run `renv::install("gitlab::project/package")`
- This did not work for me: `renv::install("gitlab@my-gitlab-server::project/package")`

Answer (score 4):

> When I run renv::init() the package source is unknown.

`renv` infers a package's source based on its `DESCRIPTION` file, which (for custom remotes) is usually annotated post-hoc by the install function itself. I suspect `install_git()` is not annotating the package in one of the ways expected by `renv`, and so `renv` is unable to infer the package source.

You could try and confirm this by checking the `DESCRIPTION` file; e.g. a quick way to dump its contents would be:

```
writeLines(readLines(system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = <package>)))
```

and check for fields like `RemoteType: git` to see if the package source has indeed been annotated.

---

For what it's worth, it looks like `devtools::install_git()` delegates to `remotes::install_git()`, and default Git credentials can be set via the `remotes.git_credentials` option. For example:

```
options(remotes.git_credentials = git2r::cred_user_pass("user", "pass"))
```

---

Ultimately though, `renv` relies on the use of a private access token (accessed via the `GITLAB_PAT` environment variable for GitLab) in order to authenticate with private repositories.

Are you able to successfully install the package using `renv::install()` with `GITLAB_PAT` set? For example:

```
Sys.setenv(GITLAB_PAT = <...>)
renv::install("gitlab::user/project")
```

This is the workflow I would recommend, and should also be supported by the `remotes` / `devtools` packages out-of-the-box.

Comment: I see `RemoteType: git2r`. I get an error when trying to install with `renv::install` after setting the `GITLAB_PAT`: `download failed [error code 22]`. I'm not sure what path to use though. My package url is http://my-gitlab-server/r-projects/package.git. In that case would the user be `r-projects`? How would I pass the server address?

Comment: I also tried: `renv::install("gitlab::server/my_user_name/package")` but I got the same error.

Comment: At this point, I think I'd recommend filing an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues as this might require more follow-up than is appropriate for Stack Overflow (and hopefully we can update the answer after we find a resolution)